# How to Disable user account after 5 consecutive failed login attempts using Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I have a use case where user should be disabled when he enter wrong password 5 consecutive times.
I cant find any keycloak password policy to disable user when he enter wrong password 5 consecutive times.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To enable Consecutive Failed Login Defence you need to enable "Max Login Failures" from Brute Force Detection.
Steps:

1. Login to Keycloak Admin Console
2. Select Realms from List
3. Go To Realm Settings >> Security Defenses >> Brute Force Detection
4. Enable **Brute Force Detection**
5. Set **Max Login Failures** to 5

Refer screenshot for steps[image]

Comment: What happens after 5 failed login attempts?

Comment: Account will be locked for few hrs/mins according to configuration

Comment: but no declarative message appears to the user that his account is locked.

Answer (score 10):

Go to Your Realm > Realm Settings > Security Defenses > Brute Force Detection and enable it. Inside the Brute Force Detection page you will find many options, the ones you are interested in are "Max Login Failures" and "Permanent Lockout"